# Retrieving data with foreign keys laravel react

Tags: php, mysql, reactjs, laravel

I have two table in mysql one called category with id and name (e.g 1 Dress)

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

Second table called clothes with foreign key category_id (e.g 1, Black Dress, very cool,10.99,/images.img1,10,1)

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('clothes', function (Blueprint $table) {
         $table->increment('id');
        $table->string('item');
        $table->string('description');
        $table->double('price');
        $table->string('img');
        $table->integer('stock');
        $table->integer('category_id');

        });
        Schema::table('clothes', function($table) {
            $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('categories');
        });
    }
```

So what I am trying is with react fetch information with name category.

```
componentDidMount(){
        axios.get('product')
        .then(response => {
          this.setState({ products: response.data });
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
          console.log(error);
        })

render(){
    return (
        <div className="container">
        <h5>Products</h5>
        <br />

<div className="row justify-content-center">
             {this.state.products.map((data,mykey)=>
          <div  className="card"  key={mykey}>
             <img className="card-img-top" src={data.img}></img> 
             <div className="card-body">
             <h4 className="card-title"><b>{data.item}</b></h4>
             <p className="card-text">{data.description}</p>
             <ul className="list-group list-group-flush">
    <li className="list-group-item"><b>Price: {data.price}$</b></li>
    <li className="list-group-item"><p>{data.category_id} <Button>Yess</Button></p></li>
  </ul>

    </div>

</div>

            )}
           </div>
        </div>  

    )
  }
```

In web.php

```
Route::get('product', function(){ return App\Clothes::all(); });
```

In this way I am getting just the number of category but I want to get the name of category.

I would appreciate any type of idea or help to get the name of category not just id.

UPDATE::
Clothes.php

```
class Clothes extends Model
{
    //
    protected $fillable = [
        'id', 'item','description','price','img','stock', 'category_id'
    ];

}
```

Category.php

```
class Category extends Model
{
    //
    protected $fillable = [
        'id', 'name'
    ];
}
```

Comment: have you setup the relationships?, with eloquent you should be able access the category name

Comment: Would you be kind explain how to add it, I have posted all code that I have done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to fetch categories as well:

```
Route::get('product', function(){ return App\Clothes::with('category')->get(); });
```

This would work if models and relations properly defined.

In cloths model add this:

```
public function category()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Category', 'category_id' );
}
```

In category model add this:

```
public function clothes()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Clothes', 'category_id' );
}
```

Comment: "message": "Call to undefined relationship [Category] on model [App\\Clothes].",
    "exception": "Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\RelationNotFoundException", I have edited question and added my Category.php file but this is not working

Comment: You are the best! Thank you sooo much :D

Comment: You need to read about laravel eloqvent relations. Most apps revolve around that staff.